# Get digital signature from the UI and use it in the transaction for verification.(Blockchain- Corda R3)

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am very new to blockchain-corda R3 and i have got one task to create some party node, put some constrain and get the digital signature from the UI.
Please help me to get started with this as I have gone through the corda docs but I didn't get the solution properly.
Request you to please help me with the flow.
How we can get the digital signature from UI and also how we can sign transaction and validate in other node.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean saying "digital signature from UI"? Is it signing a transaction in a mobile/web app without disclosing your private key (like in crypto wallets)?

Comment: @maxtaldykin Sorry for the wrong description above as I misunderstood.
My task is to have three party node with some contracts and once the transaction is done successfully between all three parties then using an api, we should be able to get the final status as approved or rejected.

Comment: then, in this case the answer I gave below is correct.

Comment: Yeah that cover most of my question. Still have one doubt regarding getting the status from an API after the contract is signed between all the parties. I need to know whether the party A, B and C all have signed the transaction or not. 
Lets say Party A is signed then the status should be 'Proposed', if PartyA and PartyB both have signed then the status should be 'Pending' and if all three party has signed then the status should change to 'Approved'
And theses status should be fetched from an API.

Comment: @user3930728  I updated my answer after these new details given in your comment. Could you please update the question as well? If you find my answer acceptable, please do not forget to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- [check this out](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Basic/cordapp-example/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/example/flows/ExampleFlow.kt) on how to create a flow and how to validate the transaction in both parties (i.e. *@Initiating* and *@InitiatedBy* flows)
- by "digital signature" I guess you mean the signature of the final transaction signed by all interested parties. If this is the case, your flow needs to return a `SignedTransaction` object and it can be done easily just by doing this standard step at the end of your flow
  `return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession))` ([usage example](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/37ed0055703405a1c5ffc77bef136b813c9c4d6e/Basic/cordapp-example/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/example/flows/ExampleFlow.kt#L105)).
- If you want to see the status of all intermediary steps of a transaction before it is fully signed and notarized, Corda provides a `ProgressTracker` ([documentation](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.8/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.utilities/-progress-tracker/index.html)) that allows you to check create `steps` so that they can be showed from node terminal. You could reorganize your flows and API in order to take advantage of this.